# Getting a div to have a bottom scroll bar in IE8 - Attempt 2?

Tags: css, html, overflow

This is my second attempt at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154723/getting-a-div-to-have-a-bottom-scroll-bar-in-ie8).  I made a mess of the first attempt and have requested that it be deleted.

So, I basically have a lot of small `item` divs 100px wide which I want on a single horizontal line (they must not wrap to the next line ever), contained within another div `container` 300px.

I need the `container` div to have a horizontal scroll bar, so I can scroll left and right, without allowing the smaller `item` divs to wrap to the line(s) below.

Keeping in mind that i will not know how many `item` divs the end result will contain in the `container` div as they will be generated dynamically.

Is it possible to do this in IE8?

In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M2sgv/9/) example, the only problem seems to be that the `item`s are wrapping to the lines below.  I think if they stay on the single top horizontal line, the horizontal scrollbar will work.

Comment: You should have just edited the question! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `float: left`, use `display: inline-block` on `.item`. Then, add `white-space: nowrap` to `.container` to prevent wrapping.

This will work in IE7/8 and all modern browsers.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/M2sgv/22/

```css
.container {
    width: 300px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.item {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline; /* for ie7 */
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution http://jsfiddle.net/M2sgv/21/

Just added another container with fixed width of "1200px", you could choose any width of your choice. Secondly, I added "overflow:auto;" to the container div's css and deleted overflow-x, overflow-y. These two are not supported by all browsers, so avoid using them. The above solution works on all browsers.

Comment: what if the combined width of added items increase 1200px?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to achieve this, here is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M2sgv/23/)

Here is the updated code:-

**JQuery Code:-**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var contWidth = $('.container .item').length * $('.container .item').width();
   $('.container').width(contWidth);    
});​
```

**HTML:-**

```
<div class="scrollContainer">
    <div class="container">    
        <div class="item">item 1</div>
        <div class="item">item 1</div>
        <div class="item">item 1</div>
        <div class="item">item 1</div>
        <div class="item">item 1</div>
        <div class="item">item 1</div>
        <div class="item">item 1</div>
        <div class="item">item 1</div>
        <div class="item">item 1</div>
        <div class="item">item 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

​
**CSS:-**

```
.scrollContainer 
{
    width: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.item
{
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
```

​
**EDIT:- The `scrollContainer` width can be any as per your requirement.**